# Stats don't match up after applying a user-defined format

Tags: sas

I have a specific output that I need to obtain after applying a user-defined format to a variable from a csv file.

Here's the format:

```
proc format;

value ClassSize 
low - <10 = 'Very Small'
10 - <14 = 'Small'
14 - <18 = 'Medium'
18 - <22 = 'Large'
22 - high ='Very Large'
 . = 'Unknown'
;
run;
```

This seems all well and good, since all the values are accounted for. However, when I run a proc freq, I get 152 counts of "Very Small" instead of the 115 I'm supposed to have. The "Unknown" count is correct, but all of the others have had some of their counts stolen by the "Very Small" Group.

"Very Small" is supposed to have values less than 10. Then, "Small" is to be from 10 to 14 (but not including), and so on and so forth, until the "Very Large" is supposed to be 22 and up.

Am I missing something? Everything seems like it should get me the correct counts, but it doesn't.

Comment: Format looks fine to me. It's possible to have surprising results due to numeric precision issues if you think you have a value of 14 but SAS has stored it as 13.999999999 or whatever. Assuming these are integers, you could round the values to make sure that hasn't happened. Would also start looking at the values to double check, e.g. `proc format data=have; tables classSize; where put (classSize, classSize.)="Very Small";run; ` Something like that should show you all the values that are labeled as very small by the format.

Comment: It turns out that it was nothing more than that SAS Studio corrupted the data/format. I resubmitted the format under a different name, reapplied, and saw the correct numbers. Unfortunately, this wasn't until after a lot of playing around with rounding, etc.